# How to test Browser support for Background-clip: text?

Tags: javascript, css

How would you test the value of background-clip: text, webkit supports text, but mozilla and other browsers do not I have tried modernizr teststyles but no luck

Comment: `background-clip: text` has never existed in CSS3. I'm not surprised Modernizr doesn't contain a test for it.

Comment: it exists in webkit thats why i am asking how to test for support of the value text, mozialla dosent support background-clip: text

Comment: Here's an article on it from a quick Google, might provide some answers for you:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/12/experiments-with-background-clip-text/

Comment: Yea i saw that but it dosent really give any advice on testing for support of 'text' in the browsers that support background-clip but dont support 'text'

Answer (score 6):

```
var testEl = document.createElement( "x-test" );
var supportsWebkitBackgroundClipText = typeof testEl.style.webkitBackgroundClip !== "undefined" && ( testEl.style.webkitBackgroundClip = "text", testEl.style.webkitBackgroundClip === "text" );
```

Comment: this returns true regardless of support. Tested on firefox, opera

Comment: @Lawrence Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`@supports` CSS at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports):

As an example:

```css
.colorful {
  color: #0098db;
}

@supports (background-clip: text) or (-webkit-background-clip: text) {
  .colorful {
    background: #0098db;
    background: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      #0098db 0%,
      #0098db 45%,
      #c9d9ec 45%,
      #c9d9ec 100%
    );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS.supports in your js. The CSS.supports api works for all browsers except IE, where this property doesn't work anyway so that's fine.

```
let supported = CSS.supports && CSS.supports('-webkit-background-clip', 'text');
```